# How to get the value of a key-value-pair Json via SQL in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena

I have this Json:

```
'[{key=342, value=someword}, {key=317, value=anotherword}, {key=229, value=yetanotherword}]'
```

I want to get the value where the key is equal to 317 via SQL in Amazon Athena. In other words: I want the output to be 'anotherword'. So I tried:

```
SELECT * where json_extract('[{key=342, value=someword}, {key=317, value=anotherword}, {key=229, value=yetanotherword}]', '$.key')=317;
```

How can I get the value where the key is equal to 317 via SQL in Amazon Athena?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: @AftabAnsari  no. net yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you have json data stored in s3 bucket and below steps can  be used to get expected result

1)  I have created a sample json file “sampleJson.json” and uploaded to s3 bucket. You can download it from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eRO8owJk5oZCNFHn5eoytFHvA1UbAfFn/view?usp=sharing)

2)  Creat a external table that will point to s3 bucket where you have stored “sampleJson.json” file(s)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE JsonExtTable(
  sampledata string
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://<s3 bucket path>'
```

3)  Query the above created external table to get the expected result

```
Select 
items['key'] key
,items['value'] value
from JsonExtTable
cross join unnest(cast(json_extract(sampledata, '$') AS ARRAY<MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>>)) t (items)
where items['key']='317';
```

**Query result**
[image]

Above steps might help you to get the exact solution or will give some clue.